# Is there an automated way to create projects and namespaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I need to create a directory structure as well as namespaces for approximately 100 separate projects that would have namespacing like the below syntax:

```
BusinessArea.DataSource.Capability
```

Some examples include:

```
Customers.SalesForce.Accounts
```

and this would correspond to the following directory structure:

```
Customers
--SalesForce
----Accounts Project
```

.

```
Billing.SalesForce.Invoices
```

and this would correspond to the following directory structure:

```
Billing
--SalesForce
--Invoices Project
```

.

```
AccountsReceivable.Dynamics.Products
```

and this would correspond to the following directory structure:

```
AccountsReceivable
--Dynamics
--Products Project
```

**Is there an automated way to generate this directory structure as well as the projects?**

Comment: I don't think there exists nothing so specific already created, but creating a program which does that should be a trivial matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  C# project  (I am assuming C# based on the question being tagged as C#) projects are `.csproj` files that are really XML files with a special extension.  Create a template `.csproj` file in Visual Studio and then view that file in a text editor (e.g. notepad) to see what the XML should look like.

The `System.Xml` namespace contains support for authoring XML files which can be used to create the `.csproj` files.

The `System.IO` namespace contains support for creating directories.

Between these two namespaces in the framework, you have the tooling needed to automate the creation of directory structure and project files from C#.